# Linq nested collection filter

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Brand` and `Area` view models containing their respective `Id`s. 
`Brand` view model has a collection of `Areas`.

```
public class BrandViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<AreaViewModel> _areas;

    public ObservableCollection<AreaViewModel> Areas
    {
        get { return _areas; }
        set { Set(() => Areas, ref _areas, value); }
    }
}
```

I have `SelectedAreas` collection which has the matching `Id`s with the `AreaViewModel`.

I have collection of `BrandViewModel`. I would like to get collection of `BrandViewModel` which is filtered by selected areas. 
Tried statement below but `Where` clause needs a bool condition.

```
filteredBrandViewModels = brandViewModels.Where(b => b.Areas
        .Where(a => SelectedAreas.Select(sa => sa.Id).Contains(a.Id)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the inner `Where` with `Any`:

```
filteredBrandViewModels = brandViewModels.Where(b => 
    b.Areas.Any(a => SelectedAreas.Select(sa => sa.Id).Contains(a.Id)));
```

Then you can also change the `Select` to:

```
filteredBrandViewModels = brandViewModels.Where(b => 
    b.Areas.Any(a => SelectedAreas.Any(sa => sa.Id == a.Id)));
```

And last, in case of a lot of data, I'd recommend having the ids from `SelectedAreas` as a `HashSet<int>` so search will be an `O(n)` operation instead of `O(n^2)`:

```
var hash = new HashSet<int>(SelectedAreas.Select(s => s.Id));
filteredBrandViewModels = brandViewModels.Where(b => b.Areas.Any(a => hash.Contains(a.Id)));
```

Comment: @Janis S. - Haha that was fast. Just quickly also see the last suggestion

Comment: Thanks, was sitting with this for a while. Also for the extra mile with `O(1)`.

Comment: @JanisS. - see correction about times - the `O(1)` is for each `Contains`. As you iterate a collection it'll be `O(n)` (but instead of `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Linq methods for Enumerable `Any` and `Intersect` will be handy here:

```
filteredBrandViewModels = brandViewModels.Where(b =>
    b.Areas.Select(a=>a.Id).Intersect(SelectedAreas.Select(sa => sa.Id).Any()
)
```